# How to use Power Query to update an existing row in a master file

Tags: excel, powerquery, power-automate

I've searched for this for a while now and I'm at my wits end. I have 100 excel files that I need to consolidate into one master file. I read that Power Query will work, but it does not update if an existing row is modified. Can anyone help me? Here is what needs to happen.

- An empty master file is created and when Power Query runs for the first time it will populate this file with the data from 100 children files on a onedrive
- In any of those 100 children files, a user can go in and modify and existing row, delete an existing row, or insert a new row
- When you go back into the master file and click refresh from the query menu, all the data from the children file will be updated

I'm a total newbie to Power Query. If there is a step by step guide or another post that will be useful for me that would be awesome! Also is this possible using Flows? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try "power query load multiple files from folder" in your search engine of choice.